# Woocommerce: Display Total Price when multiple quantities of a variable product are chosen

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to display the total price of a variable product when multiple quantities are selected.  I found [this piece of code being suggested in a few different places](http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/show-product-price-times-selected-quantity-on-woocommecre-product-page/) and it works great for simple products but when used for variable products the 'Product Total' multiplies by the minimum price of the variable product.

For example.  We have a variable product with prices that range from $20 - $100

You select a $30 variation, increase the quantity to 2 and the Total Price displays $40.

When added to the cart the Subtotal comes out correct ($60).

How do we get the Total Price line to calculate based on the price of the chosen variation?

Comment: Require same solution.You found any?

Answer (score 2):

try using this code.

```
<?php
// we are going to hook this on priority 31, so that it would display below add to cart button.
add_action( 'WC_Product_Variable', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 'set priority here' );
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    // let's setup our divs
    echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>',__('Product Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    echo sprintf('<div id="cart_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>',__('Cart Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                    current_cart_total = <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total; ?>,
                    currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

                $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                    if (!(this.value < 1)) {
                        var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value),
                        cart_total = parseFloat(product_total + current_cart_total);

                        $('#product_total_price .price').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
                        $('#cart_total_price .price').html( currency + cart_total.toFixed(2));
                    }
                    $('#product_total_price,#cart_total_price').toggle(!(this.value <= 1));

                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, unfortunately, this isn't working.  The Product Total doesn't show up with this code.  We did change the priority.  We're looking for something that will return the selected variations price multiplied by the quantity.